# A lot of services do not start on boot

Tags: debian-squeeze, service, sysv

It worked before, but now it does not. A few services (like varnishd, memcached, apache2) get started on boot, but many others do not, like: nginx, php-fpm, vz.

I don't know where to look at. There is no problem in /var/log/messages or in each service log. I check and all those services are marked to run at level 2-5.

On Debian Squeeze + dotdeb.

Comment: Use chkconfig command to start the daemons on bootup.

Answer (score 1):

Check the services individual log files. My bet is that maybe you have port alignment issues. One won't start if another is running on that port like 80 for example and an update or a rebuild might have broken config files.

Comment: I checked but there is no error. Also, I can start those services manually without problem. And nginx listen on port 80, Apache on 8080, OpenVZ and php-fpm all have their own ports.